# Bootstrap Carousel Not Loading

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap framework to create a carousel, but I'm not having any success. Here are my script/CSS declarations:

```
    <link href ="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js" type=text/javascript></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carousel').carousel();
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my applicable carousel markup:

```
    <div class="carousel-container">
            <div id="carousel-main" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active"><img src="slide1.jpg" /></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="slide2.jpg /"> </div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="slide3.jpg /"> </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="carousel-main"
                    data-slide="prev">&lsaquo</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="carousel-main"
                    data-slide="next">&rsaquo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I load the page, all of the content except my carousel appears. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you specify the script type for your inline script? (the document ready)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra closing `</div>` at the end of your mark-up ..

Also don't forget to add quotes around the `type="text/javascript"` when linking your `bootstrap.js` file .. If you have an HTML 5 doctype the `type` attribute isn't needed ..

You're also referencing to your images incorrectly:

Edit: Instead of: `<img src="slide3.jpg /">` use: `<img src="slide3.jpg" />`

Comment: Thanks for catching those stupid mistakes, but even then the carousel does not appear to be loading.